# C++ Libusb isn't bringing back serial number of device

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port, libusb

I'm currently working on a project that involves bringing information back from devices plugged in via true usb. To solve this, I'm attempting to use libusb in my C++ project. I'm on Windows 10, using C++ and QT Creator with QT version 5.2.1. I can get the vendor ID and product ID of my device with .idVendor and idProduct. However, my serial number is returning as 0 with .iSerialNumber. I'll post my code below and hopefully someone can help me figure out what I'm missing or suggest another library for me to try. Thanks!

```
bool CPumpFinder::pollTrueUSB(boolean &deviceFound, Device &newDevice)
{

boolean usbFound = FALSE;
boolean accuCheckFound = FALSE;
AccuGuideCom *acc = new AccuGuideCom();

libusb_device **devs; //pointer to pointer of device, used to retrieve a list of devices
libusb_context *ctx = NULL; //a libusb session
int r; //for return values
ssize_t cnt; //holding number of devices in list
r = libusb_init(&ctx); //initialize a library session

if(r < 0) {
    return 1;
}

libusb_set_debug(ctx, 3); //set verbosity level to 3, as suggested in the documentation
cnt = libusb_get_device_list(ctx, &devs); //get the list of devices

if(cnt < 0) {

}

ssize_t i; //for iterating through the list
for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
      printdev(devs[i], usbFound, accuCheckFound); //print specs of this device
      if(usbFound == TRUE)
      {
          if(accuCheckFound == TRUE)
          {
              newDevice.displayName = "ACCU-CHEK GUIDE";
              newDevice.type = DEVICE_ACCUCHECKGUIDE;
              newDevice.vendorID = accuVID;
              newDevice.productID = accuPID;
              newDevice.serial = accuSerial;

          }
          deviceFound = TRUE;
          break;
      }
}
libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1); //free the list, unref the devices in it
libusb_exit(ctx); //close the session

return deviceFound;

}

boolean CPumpFinder::printdev(libusb_device *dev, boolean &usbFound, boolean 
&accuChekFound) {

libusb_device_descriptor desc;
int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);

if (r < 0) {
    return usbFound;
}

uint16 vID = (uint16)desc.idVendor;
uint16 pID = (uint16)desc.idProduct; //desc.iSerialNumber

//#define ACCUCHEK_GUIDE_VENDORID                (uint16)0x173A
//#define ACCUCHEK_GUIDE_PRODUCTID               (uint16)0x21D5

if((vID == 5946) & (pID == 8661))
{
    accuPID = pID;
    accuVID = vID;

    //Do serial?
    accuSerial = "Test";

    write_text_to_log_file("we did it");
    accuChekFound = TRUE;

    usbFound = TRUE;
}

if(usbFound == TRUE)
{
    libusb_config_descriptor *config;
    libusb_get_config_descriptor(dev, 0, &config);
    const libusb_interface *inter;
    const libusb_interface_descriptor *interdesc;
    const libusb_endpoint_descriptor *epdesc;
    for(int i=0; i<(int)config->bNumInterfaces; i++) {
        inter = &config->interface[i];
        for(int j=0; j<inter->num_altsetting; j++) {
            interdesc = &inter->altsetting[j];
            for(int k=0; k<(int)interdesc->bNumEndpoints; k++) {
                epdesc = &interdesc->endpoint[k];

                }
            }
        }

        libusb_free_config_descriptor(config);
        if(accuChekFound == TRUE)
        {

            return accuChekFound;
        }
        return usbFound;
    }
    return usbFound;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the device actually *has a serial number*? You'd be surprised to know how many crap devices either put in garbage or nothing at all into required fields. Just because the spec says that something is required/mandatory does *not* mean that device manufacturers actually give a damn and adhere to it. And there are *many* crap devices out there.

Comment: There's a serial number on the back of the device I'm testing with but I'm not sure there is one written into the device electronically. However, I have another device I am sure has a serial number and I get similar behavior. I'm currently reading that iSerialNumber is the index of the serial number and that I'm supposed to get the number I need from there. Not sure how to do this at the moment, but I'm going down this rabbit hole while I await responses.

Comment: You can use `lsusb` to see if it reports the serial number. I am not sure if this tool is available on Windows, but you can borrow someone's MacOS or Linux computer or use virtualized Linux and making sure the virtualization software USB mapping makes the USB device visible to the guest OS.